# Linux shell: how to Iterate multiple file lists and take action on each line in the file?

Tags: linux, list, shell, file, loops

I'm trying to iterate all files in a directory that have the FILELIST extension, which I manage to do. But then I would like to read the content of these files, containing paths and file names of other files. These files, I would like to move to another location.

```
FileA.FILELIST
/somepath/File1.csv
/somepath/File2.csv
FileB.FILELIST
/somepath/File3.csv
/somepath/File4.csv
```

What I have so far...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Iterate all file lists
for fl in /path/Inbox/*.FILELIST
do
  #Iterate the content of the current file list
  while read line; 
  do
    #Move it to the Archive directory...
  done < $fl
done
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Just replace `#Move...` line with `mv "$line" /archive/dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
ls *.FILELIST|while read file    # Reading all files named ".FILELIST" - 1 by 1.
do
    echo "File is $file"    # Your current file in the list

    cat $file|while read line    # Now reading the lines of the file
    do
        echo "Line is $line"
    done
done
```

Sample output for the provided input.

```
 >Wed Oct 05|01:54:14|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ls -lrtha *.FILELIST
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 40 Oct  5 01:52 FileA.FILELIST
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 40 Oct  5 01:52 FileB.FILELIST
 >Wed Oct 05|01:54:18|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % cat *.FILELIST
/somepath/File1.csv
/somepath/File2.csv
/somepath/File1.csv
/somepath/File2.csv
 >Wed Oct 05|01:54:23|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ./a.sh
File is FileA.FILELIST
Line is /somepath/File1.csv
Line is /somepath/File2.csv
File is FileB.FILELIST
Line is /somepath/File1.csv
Line is /somepath/File2.csv
 >Wed Oct 05|01:54:26|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp %
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks good and with a few tweaks like below, should do the job for you. I have added conditions in `read` to handle special characters if available in the file you are reading from.

```
#/bin/bash

for file in /path/Inbox/*.FILELIST
do
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line;
    do
        echo "$line"

        # mv "$line" "$targetPath"
        # Do whatever else you want to do with the line here

    done < "$file"
done
```